# NGINX try_files rewrite causes css styles to disappear when a slash is present

Tags: php, css, nginx

So I'm trying to create a mechanism to handle friendly urls with NGINX/PHP-FPM using the basic configuration further below.

When I run an address with a non-existent uri like:
http://example.com/blah/whatever

All the styling from the default page just goes away. I thought I had a sense of what's going on and searched exhaustively, but there's nothing on stack or in the logs or that comes through in Firebug or Chrome that confirms my intuition.

Following is my nginx config:

server

```
listen 192.168.1.80:80 default_server;
listen 192.168.1.80:443 default_server ssl;

root /home/main/jb/www/;        
client_max_body_size 30M;

# access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    index index.php;
    include mime.types;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~ \.php$ {
     root   /home/main/jb/www/;
     try_files $uri =404;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
     fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_index  index.php;
     fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

     include fastcgi_params;

     fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
     fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME $http_host;             
     fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
     fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
     fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
     fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
     fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
     fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
     fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
     fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}
location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
}
```

Comment: It's great that you solved your own problem. I have moved your answer to the answer section, as to not get in the way of the question.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Disclaimer: This was extracted from the question.</sub>

I seemed to have solved the problem by adding a full url to all the respective script and link tabs where before I was just using relative paths. Not sure if I fully understand the dynamics of the solution, but I hope this helps.